# Does my own answer deletion/undeletion count towards the votes?

Tags: support, voting

After answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056647/jquery-mousedown-mouseup-prevent-click), I realized that my answer didn't really solve the problem, so I decided to delete it while I thought a bit more about the problem and how to solve it. I made some changes, undeleted the answer, but after more thinking I deleted it again, to finally undelete it permanently.

In the edit history, I can see my deletion/undeletions:

[image]

And in my profile, I can see that those deletions/undeletions are counted towards the votes I cast:

[image]

Why is that? Do they really count for receiving badges? If it happens (Civil Duty doesn't specify anything about own content as the Copy Editor does), it seems a bit counterproductive.

I have done deletion/undeletion on my own answers in the past, and now I feel like I have broken some SO/SE rule without realizing. Are there any rules/restrictions on when to delete/undelete own content? (and where could I read about it)

Comment: I can't spot any vote cast changes upon your posts at the linked Q&A??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added a couple of screenshots of the edit log and my votes cast

Comment: OK, I was talking about up-/downvotes on your posts there, that was a misunderstanding from my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be sure, but I believe Civic Duty only applies to up/down votes, not closure or deletion votes.

You haven't done anything wrong here (though a mod may comment on the post to make sure everything is OK). When you delete a post, you cast a deletion vote against it. Since you are the OP, it reaches the deletion threshold immediately and is deleted. It shows up as such in your vote history.

Basically, you have nothing to worry about here.

Comment: You are right. Checking SE, it states "Upvotes and downvotes on questions and answers count". It also mentions that comment votes and community wiki votes don't count, but it doesn't say anything about delete/undelete votes